# Upload Image to S3 bucket from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i try this code in node.js lambda, it works, it insert my picture in my s3 bucket, but when i try to open the picture in s3 bucket, it wont render, anyone knows why ? i expect that the picture URL can be accessed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XZBI.png)

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();


exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    
    // Extract picture data from the event (e.g., base64 encoded data)
    const pictureData = event.pictureData;

    // Specify the S3 bucket and object key
    const bucketName = 'BUCKET NAME';
    const objectKey = 'lambda/your-object-key3.jpg'; // Adjust the file extension accordingly

    // Convert the picture data to a buffer
    const buffer = Buffer.from(pictureData, 'base64');

    // Upload the picture to S3
    await S3.putObject({
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: objectKey,
      Body: buffer,
      ACL: 'public-read', // Optionally set ACL for the uploaded object
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    }).promise();

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify('Picture uploaded successfully'),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error uploading picture:', err);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify('Error uploading picture'),
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: How are you attempting to "open" the image file? Is it via the console, via a URL, inside an HTML file using `<img>`? What do you mean by "it won't render" -- what happens?

Comment: via URL @JohnRotenstein

Comment: What happens? Do you receive an error message? Does anything appear in the browser's Developer Console?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i edited my question description, it shows exactly like that when i access the image via URL, do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `upload` method instead

```js
await S3.upload({
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: objectKey,
  Body: buffer,
  ACL: 'public-read', // Optionally set ACL for the uploaded object
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
}).promise();
```

You can also try to pass your image via Form Data instead of using base64 format in the request body.

Comment: still not works unfortuantely

Comment: @BrianWidjaja in this case please share an example url with your uploaded image

Comment: https://mvcflowershoptp058847.s3.amazonaws.com/lambda/your-object-keykont.jpg

Comment: The linked image file is not in a valid format.